# Read SPecific lines of a CSV file in R-language

Tags: r

I am trying to write a code which manipulates data from a particular .csv and writes the data to another one.
I want to read each line one by one and perform the operation.
Also I am trying to read a particular line from the .csv but what I am getting is that line and the lines before it.
I am a beginner in R-Language, so I find the syntax a bit confusing.

```
    testconn<=file("<path>")
    num<-(length(readLines(testconn)))
    for(i in 1:num){
    num1=i-1
    los<=read.table(file="<path>",sep=",",head=FALSE,skip=num1,nrows=1)[,c(col1,col2)]
    write.table(los,"<path>",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE,sep=",",col.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)
    }
```

This is the code I am currently using, thought it is giving the desiored output but it is extremely slow, my .csv data file has 43200 lines.

Comment: Are you looking for this `read.table(file=<path>,sep=",",head=FALSE)[2,]`?

Comment: nope BTW i found the solution by using a combination of nrows and skip in the read.table function.

Comment: It is encouraged to answer his own question in SO. BTW: I don't understand your solution ...

Comment: (skip = n-1,nrows=1), this skips the n-1 lines and takes only the nth line into consideration.

Comment: ummm...I hope you are not putting this in a loop to read your file line by line!

Comment: I tried to and it messed up the output, what could be the issue with this?

Comment: There are lots of reasons output could be 'messed up'. We might be able to help if you can post the actual file (e.g. to Dropbox) and state a little more clearly what your specific goal and problem is.

Comment: @DrewSteen, but ultimately, we're not here to do their work for them for them for free, just point them in the right direction to solve their problem. Trying to recreate a small reproducible example would be a much better approach than posting their actual file to Dropbox, especially in the long run.

Comment: I have edited the question and included the code, kindly view it

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I absolutely take your point, and a minimal example is generally best. But in fact I am sometimes here to do peoples' work for free - almost everything I know about R I have learned by first asking questions and then posting answers to SO. In fact, from a selfish perspective, that's really the only reason I go on SO: to teach myself something by working on someone else's problem. This one looks like it has something to do with teh specific nature of the .csv file.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your code doesn't work. You confuse the comparison operator **<=** and the assignment one **<-**
2. Your code is is extremly innefficient. You call both `read.table` and `write.table` **43200 times to read/write a single file**.

You can simply do this:

```
    los<- read.table(file="<path>",sep=",")[,c(col1,col2)]
    res <- apply(los,1,function(x){## you treat your line here}
    write.table(res,"<path_write>",row.names=FALSE,
                       quote=FALSE,sep=",",col.names=FALSE)
```